# Прямая речь и слова автора

Tags: диалог

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста относительно прямой речи и слов автора, нигде не смог найти ответ на свой вопрос.

Вопрос следующий. Если после прямой речи идут слова автора, затем точка, может ли после точки идти следующее предложение слов автора?

И правильно ли я понимаю, что слова автора — это конструкция, относящаяся непосредственно к прямой речи, а не к тексту вообще, который не является прямой речью?

Например:
— Ты не прав, — сказал Френк, посмотрев на брата. В глазах Френка читалось презрение.
(Абзац) Повисла напряженная пауза.

В данном примере текст после абзаца не относится к прямой речи и не является словами автора, я правильно понимаю?

И является ли словами автора предложение: В глазах Френка читалось презрение?

Comment: Максим, уточните, к какому конкретно  месту в вашем примере относится вопрос. По тому, что написано, получается, что сомнения вызывает оформление слов ***"...сказал Френк, посмотрев на брата. В глазах Френка читалось презрение"*** в два предложения, но в одну строчку. Т. е. сомнительна точка после слова "брат".

Comment: Меня смущает тот факт, что получается конструкция: - П, - a. A.
Ни в одной книге мне не удалось найти ничего подобного. Везде после точки в словах автора идет следующий абзац.
Поэтому и не могу понять - можно ли после прямой речи написать слова автора, поставить точку и начать еще одно предложение без абзаца, учитывая, что это предложение логически относится к словам автора.

И у меня имеется некоторое непонимание. Слова автора являются частью конструкции (- П, - а. и пр.) или же слова автора - это все, что не является прямой речью?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В этой теме важно понимать **терминологию.**

1) **Предложения с прямой речью**. Предложения с прямой речью состоят из слов автора и собственно прямой речи, причем рассматривают различные варианты их взаимного расположения.

2) **Прямая речь** — высказывание, дословно введённое в авторский текст . Это точно воспроизведённая чужая речь, переданная от лица того, кто её произнёс или написал.

3) **Слова автора ― условное название**. Это слова, указывающие на то, кому принадлежит прямая речь (или это слова автора, **вводящие прямую речь**). Практически слова автора ―  это **часть авторского текста**, примыкающего к прямой речи, так что образуется **единая конструкция, оформленная с помощью определенных правил.**

— **Ты не прав, — сказал Френк, посмотрев на брата.**  Это предложение с прямой речью, оно состоит из прямой речи и слов автора, вводящих эту прямую речь. Далее следует авторский текст (не слова автора).

Comment: Благодарю! Теперь я все понял.

Answer (score 1):

Словами автора здесь является всё после закрывающего прямую речь тире. Аналогично - при альтернативном варианте оформления прямой речи (кавычки вместо тире): всё, что в кавычках - прямая речь, остальное - слова автора. Что касается выделения в новый абзац продолжения авторского текста после точки (т. е. нового авторского предложения после авторского же текста), в справочнике Розенталя приводится такая рекомендация:

> *Текст автора, не относящийся к говорящему лицу, идущий после авторских же слов, следующих за прямой речью, выделяется в новый
>   абзац... Но если текст от автора синтаксически связан с предложением,
>   вводящим прямую речь (соединительным или присоединительным союзом), то
>   он в новый абзац не выделяется*

Ссылка (см. также примеры): [§ 52. Абзацы при прямой речи](http://www.e-reading.club/chapter.php/48854/75/Rozental'_-_Spravochnik_po_russkomu_yazyku._Punktuaciya.html)

Если следовать этому правилу, то "авторское" предложение "*В глазах Фрэнка читалось презрение.*" **относится к говорящему лицу** и потому обоснованно примыкает к части авторского текста, завершающей предложение, содержащее прямую речь. Предложение "*Повисла напряженная пауза.*" формально не относится к говорящему (хотя и допускает трактовку, что это была пауза в речи Фрэнка) и не содержит "синтаксически связывающих союзов". Отнесение его к новому абзацу было бы в духе данного правила, если бы оно следовало за первым предложением. Но имеющийся случай (третье предложение идёт после чисто авторского текста) не оговорен, поэтому решение, начинать ли следующий абзац, должно определяться общими правилами деления текста на абзацы, т. е.  зависит от степени смысловой связи между вторым и третьим предложениями (на мой взгляд, "*Повисла...*" можно было бы и не выделять в новый абзац).

Comment: *Текст автора, не относящийся к говорящему лицу, идущий после авторских же слов, следующих за прямой речью, выделяется в новый абзац..* - а это имеет отношение к вопросу? Т. е. вы считаете, что вопрос об абзаце ***перед*** словами ***"В глазах Френка..."***?  У него же там в другом месте абзац, после этих слов. Впрочем, здесь слова автора однозначно ***относятся*** к герою.

Comment: Вопрос о _статусе_ предложения **В глазах Фрэнка...** ставился, пусть и в специфической форме. Поэтому не лишне пояснение роли этого и следующего за ним предложения в делении всего текста на абзацы.

Comment: А какое отношение деление на абзацы имеет к "статусу" предложения? Я из вашего текста совершенно не поняла, о чем вы вообще говорите. Другое дело, что я и сам вопрос не понимаю. Если связать тот самый "статус" с вопросом о необходимости абзаца перед этими словами, вопрос  по крайней мере будет понятен (но не ваш ответ). Хотя я и сомневаюсь, что речь об этом...

Comment: После текста примера (**прямая речь перед словами автора**), приведённого **с делением на абзацы**, поставлен вопрос: _Если после прямой речи идут слова автора, затем точка, может ли после точки идти следующее предложение слов автора?_ Поскольку после точки произведение, текст которого уже определён, не обязано заканчиваться, этот вопрос имеет смысл лишь в аспекте: _может ли следующее предложение продолжить тот же абзац или его нужно перенести в новый?_ На это и дан ответ.

Comment: Вы ушли от ответа. Повторяю прямой вопрос. Вы (и по вашему мнению - автор) говорите о точке (и абзаце) слов ***"В глазах Френка..."*** или после слов ***"сказал Френк, посмотрев на брата"***???

Comment: Разумеется, о точке после "... брата".

Comment: Так вот я и спрашиваю, ***какое отношение к этой точке, после "брата", имеет деление текста на абзацы?***

Comment: ---- Вот увидела ответ Екатерины. Я не согласна с Категоричность, но я понимаю о чем она говорит. Вы обо этом же? Если да, все вопросы к Вам снимаются, пошла задавать их Екатерине. Спасибо.

Comment: Alex_ander, я правильно понял, что конструкции вида - П, - а. A. A. (абзац) являются корректными, если все три предложения после прямой речи логически связаны с прямой речью? В книгах не видел ни единого случая, чтобы после - П, - a. шло еще одно предложение, которое не начиналось бы с абзаца.

Comment: Это следует из правила в справочнике, поскольку там сказано  "**текст** от автора, синтаксически связан... он в новый абзац не выделяется", а не "**первое предложение**" авторского текста после точки. Насколько этому правилу следуют, действительно, стоит поискать в _печатных_ книгах - поскольку на веб-страницах структура абзацев часто разрушается (так и в процитированном по сети справочнике, даже в примерах).

Answer (score 0):

> Вопрос следующий. Если после прямой речи идут слова автора, затем
>   точка, может ли после точки идти следующее предложение слов автора?
>
> Например: — Ты не прав, — сказал Френк, посмотрев на брата. В глазах
>   Френка читалось презрение. (Абзац) Повисла напряженная пауза.

Вопрос не совсем понятен. Ваше предложение оформлено совершенно правильно. Все что идет после точки - это другое предложение, оно никак не влияет на пунктуацию предыдущего и не может сделать первое "правильным" или "неправильным". Вопрос о том, нужен ли там абзац и что идет после я выношу за скобки.

Можно, наверное и по-другому всё это оформить, в одно предложение, но не вижу причин считать, что так будет лучше.

> И правильно ли я понимаю, что слова автора — это конструкция, относящаяся непосредственно к прямой речи, а не к тексту вообще, который не является прямой речью?

Этот вопрос тоже скорее умозрительный. Формально слова автора - это все, что не является словами героя или цитатой. Но вне формулировки правил оформления прямой речи само "понятие слова" автора не используют. Так что можете смело считать, что в любом правиле слова автора ограничиваются одним предложением. В следующем предложении ели будут, то уже другие слова автора.

На всякий случай добавлю. Есть некоторая сложность в оформлении предложений, в которых слова автора **разрывают** прямую речь, там приходится задумываться, одно ли тут предложение или два.

> § 196. Предложение, стоящее при прямой речи и указывающее, кому она
>   принадлежит («слова автора»), может:
>
> в) разрывать прямую речь на две части; в этом случае ставятся:
>
> ....
>
> после слов автора – точка, если первая часть прямой речи представляет
>   собой законченное предложение, и запятая – если незаконченное...

Но это трудно как-то связать с вашим вопросом - в том виде, как он задан.

Comment: Пожалуй, согласен, что мой вопрос задан несколько не корректно. Попробую его уточнить.
1) Что есть слова автора - часть конструкции (- П, - а. и пр.) или это любой текст автора, не являющийся цитатой и прямой речью?
2) Какими правилами определяется, возможно ли после точки в словах автора написать очередное предложение слов автора, логически относящееся к прямой речи? Мне не удалось найти ни одного примера, в котором после точки в словах автора не начинался бы новый абзац.

Answer (score 0):

1. — Ты не прав, — сказал Френк, посмотрев на брата.

   В глазах Френка читалось презрение.

   Повисла напряженная пауза.
2. — Ты не прав, — сказал Френк, посмотрев на брата (в глазах Френка читалось презрение).

   Повисла напряженная пауза.

**Предложение *Вглазах Френка читалось презрение* необходимо писать или с новой строки, или оформить как продолжение слов автора. Например, в виде вставной конструкции.**

Comment: Екатерина, а почему так императивно-то? Разве есть требование, чтобы каждое предложение с прямой речью оформлялось отдельным абзацем?  Да, тут нет соединительного союза, но ведь даже через точку написанное это второе предложение - продолжение слов автора, нет? И относится к говорящему. Т. е. все необходимые условия сохранения единого абзаца соблюдены.

Comment: Вот именно в этом-то у меня и вопрос. Изучив несколько книг - я нигде не смог найти конструкцию вида: - П, - а. А.
Поэтому и пытаюсь разобраться - можно ли после точки написать очередное предложение, логически относящееся к словам автора после прямой речи. 

Ну и хотелось бы понять терминологию - является ли словами автора весь текст, не являющийся прямой речью или нет. Если да, то конструкции вида: - П, - a. A. A. допустимы.

Comment: Уверена, что второе предложение надо писать с абзаца. Слова автора просто вводят прямую речь, указывая на говорящего. А всё остальное - дополнительная информация, которая должна быть оформлена новым абзацем.

Comment: Если прямая речь оформляется кавычками и находится внутри абзаца, тогда, я думаю, может быть такая ситуация. У Лескова в "Очарованном страннике" много  абзацев с прямой речью внутри, оформленной кавычками. Интересно будет найти пример. Поищу.